# RewriteEngine, как сделать перенаправление с поддомена?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

На поддомене *info.domain* нужно оставить доступными только адреса вида *info.domain/suggest* *,
а все остальные заворачивать на домен. Написал вот такое правило:

```
#info.moygorod/suggest
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^info\.(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/suggest
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/ [R=301,QSA,L]
```

но почему-то исключение !^/suggest не срабатывает, все ссылки с info.domain летят на domain. Что сделано не так?

Comment: кстати, вот %1 у вас не должно срабатывать. только выборка из последнего Cond чпабатывает

Comment: Есть вот такое правило, оно срабатывает: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]`

Comment: такое да, а если вставить между ними еще один Cond то я не знаю, что будет в %1. но по стандарту выбока не сохраняется

Comment: так что, почему не работает не знаю, но всяко cond'ы поменяте местами

Comment: к сожалению, не помогло. эффект тот же

Comment: вы знаете, везде, где я видел его использование, строку с которой должно совпасть почему-то пишут полностью. попробуйте еще `!^/suggest.*$` а дальше куры сдохли :)